# Автоматическое скачивание файла на странице *Спасибо за заявку*

Tags: javascript, html

Все интернеты облазил, помогите. Алгоритм такой:

1. Человек вводит данные в форму на запрос каталога
2. Его отправляет на страницу (*Спасибо за заявку*)
3. Не закрывая эту страницу (*Спасибо за заявку*) должно всплыть окно с предложением сохранить файл.

Comment: идея почти такова как и залить картинку ajax'ом на сервер

Comment: @LieutenantJimDangle, ???

Answer (score 1):

Со второй страницы сделать переход на файл, не забыв указать content-disposition attachment. Перехода не будет, если браузер увидит заголовок.